# directx 9 SetTime is not member c++

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, directx-9

ok i found a tutorial on animated mesh. when im trying t use their code i get an error on this line `m_pAnimController->SetTime(..)..` it says that SetTime is not member. i thought it was mistake the author made but i found another tutorial used the same format like `var->SetTime(..)..` so im not sure what is wrong im using vb 2010.
thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try to use m_pAnimController->AdvanceTime() instead ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are certainly using a newer version of DirectX 9 than the guy who wrote the sample you are using.
The function SetTime() has been changed for AdvanceTime().